# Lookup source of application internal impl without having them as dependancies to our project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies

I’m developing plugin for a web application (It’s with Liferay, but it does apply to many other case). My project has dependency on the public interface lib from the main application, but obviously not on its internal implementation.

When debugging or simply trying to understand what a badly documented method does, I’d like to be able to navigate to the application internal. I can actually import the whole application project and add an eclipse project reference to it. This way of doing it requires Eclipse to build and validate the whole app project and slow down a lot of thing in eclipse.

What I would like to do is to be able to reference those source in a way similar to the direct project dependencies. Is there some way to do something like this with eclipse?

Comment: What are you using for dependency management? Maven? Gradle? Something else?

Comment: I use maven, still, I wouldn’t want to add a dependency in the pom. The application isn’t available as an artifact anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an artifact for the impl source (or you're not willing to add a dependency on it even temporarily), then the only option I can think of is to import it as a project into Eclipse and [turn off the auto build functionality](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_autobuild.htm). But since that's a workspace-wide option, doing so will also disable automatic building of your own project - you'd have to [manually build your project](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-75.htm&cp=0_3_12_1) when operating in this mode.

To avoid that trade-off, you could create a new workspace in which to import the main application impl and disable auto-build in just *that* workspace. Then you'd have to switch back and forth between your project workspace and the application impl workspace, but that might be acceptable to you.

Having said that, I'm not sure why it's all really necessary. Importing and building a large application can take some time, but once it's done it should not have any impact on Eclipse's operation as long as you don't touch any of the files in that application project.

Comment: I did try those three way already. The auto build turned off is painful, I did try disabling java build only for the whole app project but it makes it almost useless as the project is not even "indexed".

I used for a long time the separate workspace, it’s probably the best solution until I have to debug between both workspace and finding the impl code has to be done manually instead of ctrl+click.

Comment: The reason not to have the whole app in the same workspace is that eclipse hang in many situation (autocomplete, none scoped search) and even crash sometime. I don’t care about the initial build, it’s in the ongoing usage that it’s not working well.

Still, thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: That sounds like you have something else going on (wrong) - many people work with large projects/applications in their workspaces every day without such hangs/crashes. Consider posting the details as a separate question.

Comment: I'll give it another go seeing how the new eclipse handle it.